# Convert regex result to lowercase before applying html.replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

As part of a web application, I need to search for instances of `{/d}` or `{A-Z}` within certain sections of the site and replace these instances with an element that places a symbol. This symbol is determined by the class that it is given.

```
$(".manaCost").html(function (_, html) {
   return html.replace(/\{([\d]|[A-Z])\}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-cost ms-$1\"></i>")
});
```

The code above works fine for numbers only, however, with the way the libraries I am using work, it requires that `$1` be lowercase in the case that it's a letter. It's worth noting that with the API I'm using here, I'll only need to match upper case letters, however they need to be converted to lowercase before I can use them.

How would I convert `$1` to lowercase (preferably in this one line if possible) before injecting the replacement mark-up?

I've tried using literals and other regex options but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".manaCost").html(function (_, html) {
   return html.replace(/\{([\d]|[A-Z])\}/g, function(fullMatch, group1) {return "<i class='ms ms-cost ms-"+ group1.toLowerCase() +"'></i>";})
});
```

Comment: Oh, this is working.
And I've learned a new thing with JS str.replace() today.

Comment: Yeah that does it! Thank you heaps :)

Answer (score 2):

The [**String.prototype.replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method can take an optional callback function as parameter, wich will be used to customise the replacement string, you can use it:

```
$(".manaCost").html(function (_, html) {
   return html.replace(/\{([\d]|[A-Z])\}/g, function(fullMatch, g) {return "<i class='ms ms-cost ms-"+ g.toLowerCase() +"'></i>";})
});
```